# button onclick="window.location.href..." not redirecting to View in different folder

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input for="IPMaquina" type="text" placeholder="IP da Máquina">
    <button>Estado Máquina</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='JCash_SubPages/VNEconfig';" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">Configuração</button>
  </div>
```

For some reason the onclick action won't redirect to the VNEconfig View and leads to a 404 Error

[image]

If I move it to the same directory it works

[image]

however I don't consider this a fix as there will be more Views and I'd like to organize it early on.

Comment: Perhaps 

`window.location.href='./JCash_SubPages/VNEconfig'`

Comment: It leads to the same error, it says the page can't be found in the exact address it is in

Comment: Do you have a action name `VNEconfig` ? Besides, what's your route ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Core controllers use the Routing middleware to match the URLs of incoming requests and map them to actions.

The ASP.NET Core MVC template generates conventional routing code similar to the following:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "default",
     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

The route template "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}":  Matches a URL path like /Products/Details/5
Extracts the route values { controller = Products, action = Details, id = 5 } by tokenizing the path.

The extraction of route values results in a match if the app has a controller named ProductsController and a Details action:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo(id);
    }
}
```

Read [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.

> the onclick action won't redirect to the VNEconfig View

You can create an action in the Home controller , go to the VNEconfig action then to redirect JCash_SubPages/VNEconfig View:

```
public IActionResult VNEconfig()
        {
            return View("JCash_SubPages/VNEconfig");
        }
```

Modify your code like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/VNEconfig';" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">Configuração</button>
```

Comment: This was really helpful, not only fixed it but I actually understood the code, thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing out the exact path of the file along with its extension?

Perhaps you need to specify it as:

```
onclick="window.location.href='JCash_SubPages/VNEconfig.cshtml';"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, I have tried copying the whole path as well and it didn't work. It doesn't seem like a syntax error, there are no errors or warnings (to do with that), it looks like some dumb obvious thing but I can't figure it out